# this.innerText show undefined

Tags: javascript, frontend

In this situation I tried to do the level menu, but this.innerText doesn`t work

```js
function levelJump() {
    console.log(this);// Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: "", location: Location, …}
    level_index = this.innerHTML; 
    console.log(this.innerText); // undefined
    goToLevel(level_index);
}

const levelJumperButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.level-jumper');
console.log(levelJumperButtons[10].innerText); // 11
levelJumperButtons.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => levelJump());
});
```

Comment: `() => levelJump()` -> `levelJump`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`item.addEventListener('click', () => levelJump());` should be: `item.addEventListener('click', levelJump);` because in an arrow function, `this` binding is not altered from what it was outside of the arrow function and you need `this` to be bound to the `item` element that causes the `click` event to be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

As the console.log is telling you, "this" inside the levelJump function doesn't refer to your .level-jumper element, but to the window object.

A possible solution is to pass your element explicitly, like this:

```js
function levelJump(item) {
    console.log(item);
    level_index = item.innerHTML; 
    console.log(item.innerText);
    goToLevel(level_index);
}

const levelJumperButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.level-jumper');
console.log(levelJumperButtons[10].innerText); // 11
levelJumperButtons.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function() {levelJump(item)});
});
```

A [working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o63jwr8y/37/).